# Solving power equation in Maple

Tags: math, solver, maple

I have a function

```
f := x -> -5.582656463587253/L^1.877207104415696;
```

If I try to solve for `x` with

```
solve(abs(f(x)) = 3, x);
```

it takes an awful lot of time to compute, and if I do it multiple times, my computer breaks down.

Shouldn't it be a simple

```
abs(-5.582656463587253/L^1.877207104415696) = 3

5.582656463587253/L^1.877207104415696 = 3

L^1.877207104415696 = 5.582656463587253/3

L = (5.582656463587253/3)^(1/1.877207104415696)
  = 1.392134989
```

Answer (score 0):

Computers are, on a basic level, stupid. And literal. Recent advantages in so called artificial intelligence non-withstanding.

Thus you find yourself giving the task to solve for `x` in an equation that does not contain the symbol `x`, only the undeclared symbol `L`. And obviously in your example computation, you solve for `L`, not for `x`.

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant to solve for `L`. Do you know if I can speed up the solve computation? I know that I want a positive value, so will it make any improvement to assume L >= 0? Can I use `fsolve` instead of `solve`? To me it looks like a rather simple computation, so I don't understand why it takes so long in Maple

Comment: You should first replace all occurrences of `x` with `L` in the code. Do that and observe the result before discussing alternative solution methods.

Comment: @CarlLove I have tried using `fsolve` but it returns the negative solution. It seems `fsolve(..., useassumptions)` is invalid with `fsolve`. How can I make sure I get the positive solution?

Comment: I answered this in your separate Question.